# Problem with slideToggle adding display: block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the slideToggle effect from jQuery. I want to use for a Show more button. I have a div with a lot of text, the first 300 characters are on the div directly, the rest is on a span tag inside the div with display: none. I want it to change into display: inline then the slideToggle is triggered, but what it does is change it to display: block. Right now I've got it on the callbackfunction ot change it to display: inline, but then the effect looks ugly because it first shows the span with display: block and then changes to display: inline :(. Is there any workaround to make this look good? I've looked at a lot of sites, and found nothing... Thanks :)

Comment: spans are supposed to display inline. why fight this behavior?

Comment: I want it to display inline, but with slidetoggle, it changes automatically to display: block

Comment: as far as I think, slide toggle manipulates the height and overflow property of the element (may be more). The CSS height does not work on inline elements hence jQuery will always `display: block` such elements before animating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you're not initially hiding with `.slideToggle()`, but rather setting `:hidden` in the CSS, which is causing `.slideToggle()` to fall back to CSS-standard (`display: block`).

If you would call the element as `display:inline` and then `.slideToggle()` it hidden on initial load, `.slideToggle()` stores the inline-state

Comment: It didn't work out for me. I gave the span display: inline in my css, and then did .slideToggle() on it when the page loads. The span was hidden, and when I toggle it, it appears with display: block =/

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/CCVLT/1/ for the inline version and http://jsfiddle.net/CCVLT for the block version of the same div. In this simple JSFiddle it works as intended by storing the CSS-supplied value and recalling it. Did you store the inline value as "style" in the html? Maybe that's why it's not working.

Comment: I have the display: inline; at a css file which loads when the page does. I don't really understand what you want to tell me :S